# How can I build a GQL from a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I am building a rspec helper to test my graphql requests.

So far this is my helper:

```
def mutation_params(name, attributes:, return_types:)
  {
    query:
      <<~GQL
          mutation {
          #{name}(
            input: { attributes: #{attributes} })
            #{return_types}
        }
      GQL
  }
end
```

and I have to declare the `attributes` like this:

```
let(:attributes) do
  <<~GQL
    {
      email: "#{email_param}",
      password: "#{password_param}"
    }
  GQL
end
```

Now I want to know what I can do to be able to simply pass my `arguments` as a hash, and have the `mutations_params` method build the GQL from that hash, by iterating over them.

```
let(:attributes) do
  {
    email: email_param,
    password: password_param
  }
end
```

Something like:

```
def mutation_params(name, attributes:, return_types)
  gql_attributes = <<~GQL 
                    { 
                    }
                  GQL
  attributes.each do |key, value|
    gql_attributes merge with 
    <<~GQL
        "#{key}": "#{value}"
    GQL
  end

  {
  query:
    <<~GQL
        mutation {
        #{name}(
          input: { attributes: #{gql_attributes} })
          #{return_types}
      }
    GQL
  }
end
```

but that obviously does not work. I think my problem is I don't really understand what that `<<~GQL` is and how to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the squiggly heredoc which was introduced in Ruby 2.3. It's like a normal heredoc but it leaves off leading indentation. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html

So in other words, it's just a string! The GQL bit is arbitrary but a nice way of communicating the purpose of the heredoc.

You could write a helper like this to turn hashes into GraphQL strings

```rb
def hash_to_mutation(hash)
  attr_gql_str = attributes.map{|k,v| "#{k}: #{v.inspect}"}.join(", ")
  " { #{attr_gql_str} } "
end
```

Then assuming attributes is a hash as in your example you could just

```rb
def mutation_params(name, attributes:, return_types:)
  {
    query:
      <<~GQL
          mutation {
          #{name}(
            input: { attributes: #{hash_to_gql(attributes)} })
            #{return_types}
        }
      GQL
  }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that was what I was looking at. A code example of how to fix the `mutations_params` would be amazing!

Comment: Added a code example. Please note that this is a pretty simple converter it just maps one format of writing key-value pairs into another. Of course the full GraphQL spec wouldn't necessarily be supported by this.

Comment: I want to suggest a change so that it actually works but it says suggested change queue is full. I need you to make the email be passed as string by adding "" around value:   `attributes.map { |key, value| "#{key}: \"#{value}\"" }.join(', ')`

Comment: There we go, I just approved the change. Thanks for that! It's a good example of why this type of converter is limited. It could be named "hash_to_graphql_mutation_strings_only" and could really be improved by not quoting numbers for example :)

Comment: True! This would be a good helper method for the graphql library to provide

Comment: Just remembered that `inspect` will do this. So I updated the sample.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit more verbose, but this transform will handle nested hashes and most common input data types

```
def to_graphql_input(hash)
  input_fields = hash.map do |key, value|
    key_str = key.to_s.camelize(:lower)
    value_str = case value
      when Hash
        to_graphql_input(value)
      when Array
        "[#{value.map { |v| to_graphql_input(v) }.join(", ")}]"
      else
        value.to_json # For string, numeric, boolean, and null values
      end
    "#{key_str}: #{value_str}"
  end

  "{#{input_fields.join(", ")}}"
end
```